# Conditional OR for multiple Jenkins parameters

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm looking for a way of handling multiple parameters within a Jenkins job.

My build can either be triggered by a push to Gitlab or manually.

Gitlab passes `${gitlabSourceBranch}` as a parameter containing the branch it has received a push for. My *branches to build* setting is currently set to `origin/${gitlabSourceBranch}`. Works like a charm when pushing to Gitlab.

Unfortunately, and naturally, when triggering a manual build, it fails:

```
[...]
> git rev-parse origin/${gitlabSourceBranch}^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

So, I've set up a build parameter called `GIT_BRANCH` with default value `master`, as `${gitlabSourceBranch}` is not being set when building manually.

Long story short. Is is possible to use a condition like `origin/${gitlabSourceBranch || GIT_BRANCH}` (this one doesn't work, of course)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [EnvInject+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

In job's configuration set `This build is parameterized / Evaluated Groovy script`:

```
def map = [:]
map['GIT_BRANCH'] = GIT_BRANCH ? GIT_BRANCH : gitlabSourceBranch
return map
```

and define `Source Code Management / Branches to build` as:

```
origin/${GIT_BRANCH}
```

This should allow you to override `$gitlabSourceBranch` when passing non-empty value for GIT_BRANCH parameter.

Comment: I couldn't find `Evaluated Groovy script` in the section `This project is parameterized`, but found it inside `Prepare an environment for the run`. Using the script you provided, it now works. Thank you!

Comment: Also, `GIT_BRANCH` should not have a default value, otherwise that value will always be used.